# Download email attachment from exchange server 2003 using java jackrabbit web dav client

Tags: java, exchange-server, webdav, jackrabbit, exchange-server-2003

we can fetch email attachment using .Net WebBav through below mentioned method:

Here is the link for email attachment download from exchange server 2003 uisng .net webdav https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms877930(v=exchg.65).aspx

```
Request
X-MS-ENUMATTS /exchange/useralias/inbox/OutlookMsg.eml HTTP/1.1   
Host: www.example.com  

Response
HTTP/1.1 207 Multi-Status
```

How to fetch email attachment using java jackrabbit webdav client.?

.Net WebDav has X-MS-ENUMATTS method for fetching email attachment.
Is there any method or procedure similar to .Net WebDav for fetching email attachment from exchange server 2003?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution is [JWebDAV for Exchange](http://www.independentsoft.de/jwebdav/index.html). It contains examples how to use WebDAV protocol to work with Exchange 2003

Here is an example, how to get messages from the server:

```
import com.independentsoft.webdav.exchange.Message;
import com.independentsoft.webdav.exchange.WebdavClient;
import com.independentsoft.webdav.exchange.WebdavException;

public class Example {

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            WebdavClient client = new WebdavClient("https://myserver/exchange/emailaddress", "username", "password");

            //get single message
            Message message = client.getMessage("messageUrl");

            //get all messages from the Inbox folder
            Message[] messages = client.getMessages();

            //get all messages from the specified folder
            Message[] messages2 = client.getMessages("folderUrl");
        }
        catch (WebdavException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

more examples can be found here: http://www.independentsoft.de/jwebdav/tutorial/index.html